# Unable to run vsftpd command

Tags: terminal, homebrew, ftp

I am using Sierra 10.12.6 and by using Homebrew, `vsftpd` is installed so that I can set up an FTP server my iPad can connect to.

However, I can't run the command vsftd:

`zsh: command not found: vsftpd`

But when I try to install `vsftpd` again, i see that

`*Warning: vsftpd 3.0.3 is already installed`

I can do `man vsftpd` and that works fine.

I run `which vsftpd` at root, this returns `vsftpd not found`

I went to the `vsftpd` config file and also set `listen=YES`

So how do I run `vsftpd`?

Comment: Ok, I was finally able to locate vsftpd /usr/local/Cellar/vsftpd/3.0.3/sbin, but why doesn't which command work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`vsftpd` needs to be in your PATH**

If it's not in your PATH, it will not run nor will you be able to find it with the `which` command.

You can add it two ways:

- Append your PATH to include the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/vsftpd/3.0.3/sbin`
- Make a symlink to `vstpd` in your `/usr/local/bin` directory

I would choose the second option as you have less items to modify (`.bash_profile` for example):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/vsftpd/3.0.3/sbin/vsftpd /usr/local/bin/vsftpd
```

That said...I wouldn't be using an insecure protocol like FTP to transfer files - `scp` is a much better option.  See this [blog](http://www.simonblog.com/2009/05/17/how-to-use-ssh-to-transfer-file-on-iphone/) for details

Comment: This Ipad app I am using only supports FTP streaming that was why I wanted to learn how to set up FTP server. But thank you for such a kind answer. I will read up on scp blog you mentioned. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**vsftpd needs specific directory and permissions**

In my case the error was due to the fact that although I was in the root user I was not with the necessary permissions, so here I provide two different solutions:

Execute the command with sudo even if we are in root.

```
sudo vsftpd
```

Or also change root

```
su -l root
vsftpd
```